# Exporting Sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I exported site from production server (_admin/SiteAndListExport.aspx). All cmp files size is ~8GB. The site uses EBS ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.06.insidesharepoint.aspx ).

When I try to import that site to my dev environment using command

```
Import-SPWeb http://dev2:8080 -Path C:\spbackup\site.cmp
```

I have got error:

```
Cannot import site. The exported site is based on the template STS#0 but the destination site is based on the template SPS#0. You can import sites only into sites that are based on same template as the exported site.
```

On DEV environment I created site with "select template later" option.

1. How to resolve that error?
2. I would like to speed up exporting and importing site. Is it possible to use some dump EBS provider to ignore all files and attachments stored in EBS?
3. Is it possible to detect from ISPExternalBinaryProvider implementation that invoking RetrieveBinary method is from export proccess?

Comment: You should recreate a new site collection using the same template ID. That said, do you known there is a [sharepoint dedicated stackexchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: Ok 1. is resolved by "select template later" option on my dev machine when creating new site. I am still intresed in ISPExternalBinaryProvider described in 3.